# What is the proper way to add a map in a REST request

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Google Endpoint and for one of my entities I want to create a `POST` request that adds a map of properties. What is the right way to do it? 
I know Google Endpoint can receive a `Collection` as a parameter, but I want to add a map (unknown key values).
Should I pass a `JSON` as a parameter or just add the `JSON` in the body of the request and extract it from the `HttpServletRequest` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every JSON object is a map, so it looks like the most obvious choice. GSON makes it easy, but you can use other parsers too.

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson("{'k1':'apple','k2':'orange'}", type);
```

Comment: And parsing it to what? `Entry<String,String>`>?

Comment: Cool thanks. Moreover, I actually saw that if I add a parameter `Map<String,String> data` to the endpoint method signature I get all the JSON with all the parameters

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid passing it as a parameter. You can send it in the body of the request and then use json library to get a python object.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html